# Use Python to split a string and output each token into seperate lines?

Tags: python

```
$ echo '"a1","a2","a3"'|python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.stdin.read().splitlines()), sep='\n');"
"a1","a2","a3"

$ echo '"a1","a2","a3"'|python3 -c "import sys; [print(a, sep='\n') for a in sys.stdin.read().splitlines()];"
"a1","a2","a3"

$ echo '"a1","a2","a3"'|python3 -c "import sys,pprint; pprint.pprint('\n'.join(sys.stdin.read().splitlines()));"
'"a1","a2","a3"'
```

I have tried many different methods but none of them work for me.
I would like to print each token into a seperate line.

**Question**> How can I get the following results?

```
"a1"
"a2"
"a3"
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't have multiple lines, so why are you using `splitlines`?

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of `splitlines`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on comma instead.

```py
print('\n'.join(sys.stdin.read().split(',')))
```

Comment: echo '"a1","a2","a3"'|python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.stdin.read().split(',')));" Yes, it works now. Many thanks!

Comment: Note that you don't need to split and join, a simple `replace(',', '\n')` should do the trick

Comment: @mozway, yes, it works too. Thank you!
`echo '"a1","a2","a3"'|python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().replace(',', '\n'))"`

Comment: @q0987 So your "tokens" never contain commas?

Comment: @KellyBundy, Sorry I made two silly mistakes here. 1> I incorrectly assume that splitlines is used to split a string into lines. 2> I didn't use the delimiter correctly.

Comment: @q0987 Not sure what you mean. That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @KellyBundy, my input string has tokens seperated by ','

Comment: @q0987 Still doesn't convincingly answer the question. I didn't ask about separating but about containing.

Comment: @KellyBundy, each token doesn't contain any comma and is seperated by a comma.